# Dev Container login as another user

Tags: docker, vscode-debugger, vscode-devcontainer

I've started a docker-container on a linux server. Then created a user inside of it, after which I can login as that user using `docker exec -it -u $(HOST_USER_NAME) <docker-container name> bash`, which works fine. But now I want to debug my python code running inside the container and for that I am using Dev-Container extension to attach to the container. However, the issue is that Dev-Container always logs in as the root, and then doesn't have access to certain files that only the $(HOST_USER_NAME) have access to. So is there a way I can tell dev-container to login as the $(HOST_USER_NAME). Sorry, if this is trivial, it's my first week with docker.

I tried https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1477, which says to use docker run -u. But, the way our system is setup is that it uses docker-compose up to run the container using a docker-compose.yml file.

I also tried specifying the `user` in the docker-compose.yml, but at the time of running `docker compose-up`. But it rightly says no such user is available, because user is later created using `docker exec` inside the running container

Finally, I also thought of changing user after attaching to the container using the dev-container, but then I get following errors while running the vscode debugger:

`/opt/venv/bin/python: can't open file '/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.12.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher': [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Comment: You can rebuild the container image with a Dockerfile which created the user.


FROM debian:12\nRUN useradd -m test

Comment: Sorry, I would rather not mess with that process, because that's handled by someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, simply after logging into vscode container or the main server, press F1 and search

`Open attached container configuration file.`

update the respective configuration file to add remoteUser field as:

```
{
    "workspaceFolder": "..............",
    "remoteUser": "....",
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
        "ms-toolsai.jupyter",
        "ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap",
        "ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers",
        "ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags",
        "ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow"
    ]
}
```